# Why P=NP does not imply that halting of Turing machine solvable in polynomial time?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, np

I read somewhere that -if some how someone someday can prove that P=NP then we cannot say that halting problem is solvable in polynomial time. Can you please explain why?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CS, not programming. Try the CS stackexchange site.

Comment: but please only try [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com) after you have made yourself familiar with the [basics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) of the halting problem

Comment: @HugoRune this isn't a research level question. This belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Tim, I think cstheory.stackexchange.com is for research-level questions, but I agree that this question currently meets the standards of neither site.

Comment: @HugoRune oh I didn't realize they opened a new one. Back when I started they didn't have that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the halting problem is proven to be [not solvable at all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

So any speed improvements obviously will not make it easier to solve